# Не могу понять ошибку IllegalStateException

Tags: android

```
  public void playCycle(){
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewLeftTime.setText(getTimeString(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                viewSeekBarTime.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                if (subTitleModels!=null){
                    for (int i = 0; i < subTitleModels.size(); i++) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()>subTitleModels.get(i).getTimeStart()){
                            subTitleView.updateText(subTitleModels.get(i).getText());
                            currentIndexSubtitile=i;
                        }
                    }
                }
                playCycle();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
}
```

---

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(MediaPlayer.java)
   at com.knowledgecity.componentMediaPlayer.VideoControllerView$1.run(VideoControllerView.java:123)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

В чем ошибка? Что именно не так?

Comment: player.release(); - использовалось до вызова метода playCycle()?

Comment: Что приложение крашнулось?) не спасибо

Comment: Может мне сделать проверку на mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(). Ведь на эту строку ругается. Вся суть в том что очень трудно воспроизвести этот баг

Comment: @xTIGRx Может быть вы не отписываетесь от события ? 
1)Попробуйте увеличить делей до 5 секунд. 
2) Сделайте что-то чтобы вызвать playCycle 
3) Сразу же уйдите с этого экрана. 
4) Через 5 секунд посмотрите к логи.

Ошибка воспроизвелась?

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov, Спасибо помогло. Короче я переписал кусок кода. Тавм проблема с MediaPlayer была. Не успевает создаться а я уже запускаю ее))